# Populate an array with file information using bash

Tags: command-line, bash

To give some context, I'm trying to write a Bash script which will organise my Music directory so that it's sorted similarly to the way iTunes does: `Music/Album_Artist/Album/`.

To do this I want to first go through my Music directory and populate an array like so:

```
    ROW_INDEX - FILE_PATH - ARTIST - ALBUM_ARTIST - ALBUM - TITLE - NEW_FILE_PATH
        0
        1
        2
       ...
```

... where I'll populate all the entries save the `NEW_FILE_PATH` (which I'll populate as I move files around).

I have functions which can determine and return the file information I want, so my question is how could / should I go about making and populating the array? For example, can I do something like this - declare an array beforehand with the correct size, and then:

```
       array[i,TITLE]=`getTitle <file_name>`
```

where `i` is the row index.

I'm a Bash noob and am used to working with Matlab or Python and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: With all respect for your `bash` skills, why don't you just go and use a database?

Comment: No it's not possible, but you might fake an array: [How to make 3D array in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656130/how-to-make-3d-array-in-bash). But why don't you just use Python when you say you're used to work with it ? Or if you want to stay with bash create a `csv` / `json` string/file which you can loop through using `csvtool` / `jq`.

Comment: You'd likely want two arrays here. There's nothing like `array[i,title]` But you can have associative arrays in bash to do `${array[$title]}` with another, regular array `${array[i]}`. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: But why? Why not directly rename the files? Or print out the renaming if what you want to do is verify before committing?

Comment: It seems from the comments and from spending a couple of hours tearing my hair out that Bash wouldn't be suitable (or at least easy to use) for doing what I intended to do, so I've decided to go for a simpler approach of moving files into appropriate directories as I come across them (as suggested by @muru). I would use Python, but I'm doing this specifically to learn Bash.